# Method to display particular types of pizza from a list in Java

Tags: java, list, maps, factory-pattern

I have a simple pizza program in Java, made using the Factory Pattern.
Basically, when a factory is given as a parameter, it creates a particular pizza, which is then added to the list of pizzas of the PizzaShop.

I would like to create a method that displays how many particular pizzas I have. For instance, when the method is called, I would like it to display something like "We have 5 PizzaChicago and 3 PizzaNewYork". I am not sure how to do that.

This is my code.

```
public interface Pizza {
    String name();
}

public class PizzaChicago implements Pizza{
    public Integer price;
    public PizzaChicago(Integer price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class PizzaNewYork implements Pizza{
    public Integer price;
    public PizzaNewYork(Integer price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}


public interface PizzaFactory {
   public Pizza createPizza(Integer price);
}

public class PizzaNewYorkFactory implements PizzaFactory{
    @Override
    public Pizza createPizza(Integer price) {
        return new PizzaNewYork(6);
    }
}

public class PizzaChicagoFactory implements PizzaFactory{
    @Override
    public Pizza createPizza(Integer price) {
        return new PizzaChicago(8);
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PizzaShop {
    List<Pizza> pizzaList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void createPizza(PizzaFactory factory, Integer price){
        Pizza pizza = factory.createPizza(price);
       System.out.println(pizza.name() + " " + "was created");
        pizzaList.add(pizza);
    }

}
`
```

Comment: *Pizzas you have* means how many pizzas are stored in your `pizzaList`? You could use stream.groupingBy Pizza Name and Build the Output String out of the map.

Comment: Yes, basically like how many "PizzaChicago" and how many "PizzaNewYork" I have in my pizzaList

Comment: I [generally would not recommend using](https://armedia.com/blog/instanceof-avoid-in-code/) `instanceof` to determine your count of each `Pizza` type as your accepted answer suggests. If that information is relevant, you should should handle them as such. Either create separate counting variables to increment for each type created or store them in separate `List` collections specific to their type so you can use the `size()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is iterate the list and check what is the type of every object.

```
int countPizzaNewYork = 0, countPizzaChicago = 0; 
for(Pizza p: pizzaList){
    if(p instanceOf PizzaNewYork)
    {
     countPizzaNewYork++;
    }
    else
    {
     countPizzaChicago++;
    }

 }
System.out.println("We have "+ countPizzaChicago+" PizzaChicago and "+countPizzaNewYork+" PizzaNewYork");
```

Comment: Not a good approach. What if you need to add a new Pizza?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach (use Map instead of a List):

```
public class PizzaShop {
    Map<String, Integer> pizzaDiary = new HashMap<>();

    public void createPizza(PizzaFactory factory, Integer price) {
        Pizza pizza = factory.createPizza(price);
        System.out.println(pizza.name() + " " + "was created");
        int previousCount = pizzaDiary.getOrDefault(pizza.name(), 0);
        pizzaDiary.put(pizza.name(), previousCount + 1);
    }
}
```

Use the `pizzaDiary` map to print out your pizza counts.

Answer (score 0):

Having a separate class for each pizza could be problematic and somewhat cumbersome.  And for certain using the `class name` and `instanceof` is not the way to go.  Have you considered using an Enum to represent the Pizzas?  Here is an example of how it might work.

```
public class PizzaShopDemo {
    
    enum Pizza {
        CHICAGOPIZZA(8, "Chicago Pizza"),
        NEWYORKPIZZA(6, "New York Pizza");
        
        private double price;
        private String name;
        private int count = 0;
        
        private Pizza(double price, String name) {
            this.price = price;
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        public void update() {
            count++;
        }
        
        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new PizzaShopDemo().pizzaShop();
    }
    
    public void pizzaShop() {
        createPizza(Pizza.CHICAGOPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.NEWYORKPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.CHICAGOPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.NEWYORKPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.CHICAGOPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.CHICAGOPIZZA);
        createPizza(Pizza.NEWYORKPIZZA);
        
        for (Pizza p : Pizza.values()) {
            System.out.println(p.getName() + ", " + p.getPrice()
                    + ", " + p.getCount());
        }
        
    }
    
    public void createPizza(Pizza type) {
        type.update();
        // other stuff here.
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Chicago Pizza, 8.0, 4
New York Pizza, 6.0, 3
```

Comment: Why not just use the name of the Pizza itself to print it out?

Comment: You could do that.  But this way permits one to customize it if desired.